# Can't send emails from a Rails app using Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gmail, actionmailer

I have an app with registration using Devise gem and I have followed the Rails guide on [Action Mailer Configuration for Gmail](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#action-mailer-configuration-for-gmail) but when I click on Send me password reset instructions I don't receive any emails. This is what I have:

`config/environments/development.rb`

```
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.default :charset => "utf-8"
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost:3000' }
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address:              "smtp.gmail.com",
    port:                 587,
    domain:               "example.com",
    authentication:       "plain",
    user_name:            ENV["TODO_USERNAME"],
    password:             ENV["TODO_PASSWORD"],
    enable_starttls_auto: true
  }
```

I have updated

`config/initializers/devise.rb` with:

`config.mailer_sender = 'myemail@gmail.com'`

I have also tried chaning `authentication: "plain"` to `authentication: :plain`, I have tried [this tutorial](https://richonrails.com/articles/actionmailer-settings-for-gmail), [this](https://redpanthers.co/sending-email-rails-gmail/), [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9eFXEzOPRNs) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47474669/cant-send-email-using-gmail-on-heroku), they all provide the same configuration but it doesn't work. I have allowed less secure apps [here](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps) but no luck.  I have also tried removing

`domain: "example.com"`

completely and changing

`config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost:3000' }`

to

`config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost', port: 3000 }`

but that didn't help either. 
I've also tried:

`ActionMailer::Base.smpt_settings = {
...
}`

instead but no luck.

I'v also tried putting this config to `config/application.rb`, restarting the server severl times but no luck.

This is the console log when send =ing password reset instructions:

```
Devise::Mailer#reset_password_instructions: processed outbound mail in 15.9ms
Sent mail to [hidden email] (269.2ms)
Date: Thu, 31 May 2018 22:40:03 +0200
From: [hidden email]
Reply-To: [hidden email]
To: [hidden email]
Message-ID: <5b105da3af6e6_164325fb584383ef@Home.mail>
Subject: Reset password instructions
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<p>Hello [hidden email]!</p>

<p>Someone has requested a link to change your password. You can do this through the link below.</p>

<p><a href="http://localhost:3000/users/password/edit?reset_password_token=qeoAhLA2pevyy7wpbVEs">Change my password</a></p>

<p>If you didn't request this, please ignore this email.</p>
<p>Your password won't change until you access the link above and create a new one.</p>

Redirected to http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in
Completed 302 Found in 460ms (ActiveRecord: 9.9ms)
```

I have already tried everything.
Any ideas?

I am using Rails 5.2

Comment: Just write plain username and password. Usually `ENV["TODO_USERNAME"],` is a fetch of Heroku or another hosting service environment variables. This does not apply to development. Alternatively writes username and password to `secrets.yml` and fetch with `Rails.application.secrets.TODO_USERNAME,`. Also try `authentication: :login` instead of `authentication: "plain"`

Comment: Thanks, that worked

Comment: The problem might then be at Google. Connect to your Gmail account and check all security features. I remember having had to tick a box at Gmail settings before I switched to AWS SES. It's the same kind of security than when you connect from a new device to any of Google services...

Comment: @Maxence do you know why ENV["USERNAME"] is not loading my variables? I can see the variables are defined in rails console properly. I've also tried another approach of havign a YAML file and store them there and the same thing - variables are read properly in rails console but not in config/environmnets/development.rb. Any idea why?

Comment: Where are located these variables locally ? I have never seen it working in development. to me the only way to get them locally is through the secrets.yml file but I am not expert in Rails...

Comment: They are in my .bash_profile. I've finally managed to get this to work. I've moved to Sendgrid. They also say to put the config into `config/environment.rb`.